# escapar comillas dobles en un split javascript

Tags: modal

tengo el siguiente código que muestra en una ventana modal los resultados de la base de datos, pero por ejemplo en el campo descripción hay partes del texto guardados con comillas, por ejemplo para indicar pulgadas 3", y al momento de imprimir la información en la ventana modal, solo aparece hasta donde esta la comillas, el resto de campos ya no los imprime. Como puedo escapar esas comillas para que muestre el resto de información a partir de ahí?

```html
  $(".btn-view-producto").on("click", function(){
        var producto = $(this).val(); 
        var infoproducto = producto.split("*");      
        html = "<p><strong>Codigo:</strong>"+infoproducto[1]+"</p>"
        html += "<p><strong>Nombre:</strong>"+infoproducto[2]+"</p>"
        html += "<p><strong>Descripcion:</strong>"+infoproducto[3]+"</p>"
        html += "<p><strong>Precio:</strong>"+infoproducto[4]+"</p>"
        $("#modal-default .modal-body").html(html);
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

Existen varias posibilidades para corregirlo, así que elige la que más te guste o la que mejor te funcione, al fin y al cabo. Entiendo que el problema te lo da el array infoproducto[]. A continuación te muestro las posibles soluciones a modo de ejemplo:

**1. Mezcla comillas simples y dobles.**

```
    // simples fuera, dobles dentro
    infoproducto[4] = '<li><p>Pulgadas: 30"</p></li>';
```

---

```
    // dobles fuera, simples dentro
    infoproducto[4] = "<li><p>Pulgadas: 30'</p></li>";
```

**2. Utilizando secuencias de escape.**

```
    // SdE (\) para comillas dobles
    infoproducto[4] = "<li><p>Pulgadas: 30\"</p></li>";
```

---

```
    // SdE (\) para comillas simples
    infoproducto[4] = '<li><p>Pulgadas: 30\'</p></li>';
```

La última posibilidad que se me ocurre sería usar **`&quot;`**, que seguramente también funcionaría en este caso particular, debido al contexto HTML.

Sin embargo, si prefieres que el código JavaScript sea independiente para cualquier contexto, puedes optar por cualquiera de las opciones anteriores, 1 o 2, indistintamente.

Espero haberte sido de ayuda. Saludos.

Answer (score 1):

a mi me funciona bien el código en jsfiddle, de entrada no deberías poner comillas dobles en un attribute html, siempre debe ponerse un

```
&quot;
```

pero si no tienes de otra.

```
$(".btn-view-producto").on("click", function(){
    var producto = $(this).val(); 
    var infoproducto = producto.split("*"); 

    html = `
    <p><strong>Codigo:</strong> ${infoproducto[0]}</p>
    <p><strong>Nombre:</strong> ${infoproducto[1]}</p>
    <p><strong>Descripción:</strong> ${infoproducto[2]}</p>
    <p><strong>Precio:</strong> ${infoproducto[3]}</p>
    `
    $("#modal-default .modal-body").html(html);
});
```

puedes usar la notación de es6 que es mucho mejor, y como está indicada con "`" no deberías tener problemas con las comillas.

https://jsfiddle.net/memoadian/2t1ob3kz/16/